# Android: Gain file access to OneDrive folders through terminal app (Termux)

Tags: python, android, onedrive, termux

I have a set of Python3 scripts that I keep in my OneDrive cloud. I would like to find out a way to access and run these files from/on my android phone. I'm currently using the app Termux as a terminal, so far, I've been able to go through various folders in the `/storage/` directory. I cannot remember or track down where I read this, but one of the folders containing offline OneDrive folders and files is supposed to be in `/storage/shared/Android/data/`, however, I am denied access from ls'ing in such a folder. Ultimately, I'd really like to know if there is a way for me to access the folders in my OneDrive the same way I do from my terminal on my computer. I just need to run these scripts on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up utilizing `rclone`, to be able to copy over files to and from my phone's and my OneDrive's directories. It effectively worked like similarly to `git`, except the connection was made directly to OneDrive. The tutorial I first started following was [here](https://techieskull.com/connect-google-drive-to-windows-termux-rclone/), and the rclone site is [here](https://rclone.org/)

Comment: As a side note, *rooted* Android devices can mount rclone drives https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225612/370078